# Dual Citizen (FR/SN) - Can I enter Senegal with foreign passport?

Tags: dual-nationality, senegal

I am a French and Senegalese citizen. Is it REQUIRED to enter Senegal on my Senegalese passport? (I know it is easier... I am curious from a strictly legal perspective).

Comment: The downvoter should explain why this valid question is inappropriate in their view.

Answer (score 4):

I could find no official Senegalese source that states that 
Senegalese citizens **must** use their passports for entry (as is the case for most countries).

The Dakar Airport states that dual nationals that don't have a Senegalese passport or ID will be treated as a foreigner.

The Citizenship laws (that allow dual citizenship) makes no explicit statement about this.

---

> Note: a passenger who does not have Senegalese identity papers (passport or identity card) is considered as a foreign passenger even if he / she has a multi-citizenship and must therefore be in possession of a visa .

---

**Sources**:

- [Visas and entry conditions in Senegal - Dakar Airport](https://www.aeroport-dakar.com/visa_on_arrival_senegal.php)
- [Refworld | Senegal: Citizenship laws](https://www.refworld.org/docid/469cd69a8.html)

Comment: But Senegal requires visas for citizens of only a very small number of countries.

Comment: @phoog The point is, that it is the only semi official statement found about how they treat there own nationals when entering with a foreign passport. They don't seem to otherwise care. And that is what the OP is asking about.